# When the initial capacity of the HashSet (i.e 16) gets filled up how is the new capacity is calculated? What is the formula?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

When the initial capacity of the HashSet (i.e 16) gets filled up how is the new capacity is calculated? What is the formula?

for example:
as the size of array list increases by the formula 
New capacity  = (current capacity * 3/2) + 1

and for vectors it is
New capacity = (current capacity * 2)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 11):

The `HashSet` capacity is `doubled` when the load factor `(0.75)` is reached.

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) explains:

> The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to
>   get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of
>   entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and
>   the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal
>   data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately
>   **twice** the number of buckets.

Example:

The initial capacity of `HashSet` is `16`. When the load factor `(0.75)` is reached, i.e. `16 * 0.75 = 12`; on the insertion of the `12th` element the capacity is `doubled`, i.e. it becomes `32`.

Comment: Thank you! Short and crisp explanation! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As hashset uses hashmap internally so every time it put it will check the threshold of the entry array which is by default

```
static final int ALTERNATIVE_HASHING_THRESHOLD_DEFAULT = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and it resizes it on the load factor

```
int capacity = roundUpToPowerOf2(toSize);

threshold = (int) Math.min(capacity * loadFactor, MAXIMUM_CAPACITY + 1);
table = new Entry[capacity];
```

Answer (score 1):

HashSet is implemented using HashMap, wherein all values of HashMap points to single object and keys of HashMap comprise HashSet Values.

> Initial Capacity of HashSet = 16, Load Factor = 0.75, Threshold = 75%
>   of capacity

Which means whenever a new value is added to HashSet, it's size is checked against threshold and if size exceeds threshold HashSet goes for resizing. **Resizing makes table size double** of current size. Thus, capacity is doubled and threshold is set to 75% of new capacity.

> **Which indicates whenever size of HashSet equates or goes beyond 75% of its capacity, Resizing occurs.**

Answer (score 0):

A `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`.  According to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.addEntry%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%29), the size doubles each time an increase is needed.  Here's the code for the `addEntry` method, which is the internal method called to actually add a new entry into the table.

```
 void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
     Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
     table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
     if (size++ >= threshold)
         resize(2 * table.length);
 }
```

Note that this is an implementation detail and could change at any time.

Note also that looking at the source should ALWAYS be your first resource when you have questions about how some library class works if the information you need is not in the Javadoc (i.e. an implementation detail).